# Jquery JSON Issue (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, restlet

Recently we made our restlet application to support JSON.
For get request, below url works without any issue.

> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/subscriber/site-d.mtvi.com?format=json&jsoncallback=CALLBACK_FUNCTION

For post request , i tried below, which is not working.

> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/subscriber/site-d.mtvi.com?format=json&jsoncallback=?

i get following errors in

> **Chrome :** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>    **Firefox:** Warning: Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use
>   getAttributeNS() instead.

I am doing this in jquery.  Anything to modify in url for post request ?

Thanks
Srini

Comment: Please specify more and also tell the version of `chrome` and `firefox`

Comment: Can you show the JSON and the JavaScript

Comment: You do realize that you posted a url which only works on your computer, right?